# Detect duplicate items in recursive CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have a set of dependencies stored in my database. I'm looking to find all the objects that depend on the current one, whether directly or indirectly.  Since objects can depend zero or more other objects, it's perfectly reasonable that object 1 is depended on by object 9 twice (9 depends on 4 and 5, both of which depend on 1).  I'd like to get the list of all the objects that depend on the current object without duplication.

This gets more complex if there are loops.  Without loops, one could use DISTINCT, though going through long chains more than once only to cull them at the end is still a problem.  With loops, however, it becomes important that the RECURSIVE CTE doesn't union with something it has already seen.

So what I have so far looks like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE __dependents AS (
  SELECT object, array[object.id] AS seen_objects
  FROM immediate_object_dependents(_objectid) object
  UNION ALL
  SELECT object, d.seen_objects || object.id
  FROM __dependents d
  JOIN immediate_object_dependents((d.object).id) object
    ON object.id <> ALL (d.seen_objects)
) SELECT (object).* FROM __dependents;
```

(It's in a stored procedure, so I can pass in `_objectid`)

Unfortunately, this just omits a given object when I've seen it before in the current chain, which would be fine if a recursive CTE was being done depth-first, but when it's breadth-first, it becomes problematic.

Ideally, the solution would be in SQL rather than PLPGSQL, but either one works.

As an example, I set this up in postgres:

```
create table objectdependencies (
  id int,
  dependson int
);

create index on objectdependencies (dependson);

insert into objectdependencies values (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4);
```

And then I tried running this:

```
with recursive rdeps as (
  select dep
  from objectdependencies dep
  where dep.dependson = 4 -- starting point
  union all
  select dep
  from objectdependencies dep
  join rdeps r
    on (r.dep).id = dep.dependson
) select (dep).id from rdeps;
```

I'm expecting "1, 2, 3" as output.

However, this somehow goes on forever (which I also don't understand).  If I add in a `level` check (`select dep, 0 as level`, ... `select dep, level + 1`, `on ... and level < 3`), I see that 2 and 3 are repeating.  Conversely, if I add a seen check:

```
with recursive rdeps as (
  select dep, array[id] as seen
  from objectdependencies dep
  where dep.dependson = 4 -- starting point
  union all
  select dep, r.seen || dep.id
  from objectdependencies dep
  join rdeps r
    on (r.dep).id = dep.dependson and dep.id <> ALL (r.seen)
) select (dep).id from rdeps;
```

then I get 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, and it stops. I could use `DISTINCT` in the outer select, but that only reasonably works on this data because there is no loop. With a larger dataset and more loops, we will continue to grow the CTE's output only to have the DISTINCT pare it back down.  I would like the CTE to simply stop that branch when it's already seen that particular value somewhere else.

*Edit*: this is not simply about cycle detection (though there can be cycles). It's about uncovering everything referenced by this object, directly and indirectly.  So if we have 1->2->3->5->6->7 and 2->4->5, we can start at 1, go to 2, from there we can go to 3 and 4, both of those branches will go to 5, but I don't need both branches to do so - the first one can go to 5, and the other can simply stop there. Then we go on to 6 and 7. Most cycle detection will find no cycles and return 5, 6, 7 all twice. Given that I expect most of my production data to have 0-3 immediate references, and most of those to be likewise, it will be very common for there to be multiple branches from one object to another, and going down those branches will be not only redundant but a huge waste of time and resource.

Comment: It would be great if you add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: So, your graph is a DAG. Is it guaranteed to be a (single)  DAG , and contain no loops ?

Comment: @joop I don't think I can guarantee that, no. Something could go wrong, and I don't want to to get stuck in postgres over it. It shouldn't happen, but it could happen. It shouldn't make any difference if we don't extend out the recursion beyond objects we've already seen before, though.

Comment: @Tanktalus If I understand correctly you are seeking for [CTE - CYCLE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2#cyclic) in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @lad2025 See the *Edit* marker above, it was too big to fit in a comment box :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the connectby function which exists in the tablefunc module.

First you need to enable the module

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Then you can use the connectby function (based on the sample table you provided in the question it will as follows):

```
SELECT distinct id
FROM connectby('objectdependencies', 'id', 'dependson', '4', 0)
AS t(id int, dependson int, level int)
where id != 4;
```

This will return:
1
2
3

Here is an explanation of the parameters from documentation:

```
connectby(text relname, text keyid_fld, text parent_keyid_fld
          [, text orderby_fld ], text start_with, int max_depth
          [, text branch_delim ])
```

- relname  Name of the source relation
- keyid_fld    Name of the key field
- parent_keyid_fld Name of the parent-key field
- orderby_fld  Name of the field to order siblings by (optional)
- start_with   Key value of the row to start at
- max_depth    Maximum depth to descend to, or zero for unlimited depth
- branch_delim String to separate keys with in branch output (optional)

please consult the documentation for more information.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I can't connect directly, but it is an interesting answer, and probably the closest to what we'll end up with. The other question is whether distinct is required or not - the ideal solution wouldn't require it because it wouldn't visit a single branch more than once. We may need to write our own extension based on connectby when we get to the point where the plpgsql solution becomes a bottleneck. For that reason, I'm going to mark this as my accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

The word `dep` in the second query (after `union`) is ambiguous. In fact it is interpreted as the column of `rdeps`, not as an alias of `objectdependencies.`

```
with recursive rdeps as (
  select dep
  from objectdependencies dep
  where dep.dependson = 4 -- starting point
  union all
  select dep -- this means r.dep
  from objectdependencies dep
  join rdeps r
    on (r.dep).id = dep.dependson
) select (dep).id from rdeps;
```

This is why the query creates an endless loop. You can correct this by changing the alias:

```
with recursive rdeps as (
  select dep
  from objectdependencies dep
  where dep.dependson = 4 -- starting point
  union all
  select objectdep
  from objectdependencies objectdep
  join rdeps r
    on (r.dep).id = objectdep.dependson
) select (dep).id from rdeps;

 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
  1
  2
  1
(6 rows)
```

Or better, just by using columns, like the good Lord intended:

```
with recursive rdeps as (
    select id, dependson
    from objectdependencies
    where dependson = 4
union all
    select d.id, d.dependson
    from objectdependencies d
    join rdeps r
    on r.id = d.dependson
) 
select *
from rdeps;
```

The first query in the question is all you can do in plain sql as there is no communication between different (paralel) branches generated by a recursive query. In a functional approach you can use a temporary table as a store common to all branches. The function may look like this:

```
create or replace function rec_function(int)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare
    i int;
begin
    for i in
        select id
        from objectdependencies
        where dependson = $1
    loop
        if not exists(
            select from temp_table 
            where id = i)
        then
            insert into temp_table values(i);
            perform rec_function(i);
        end if;
    end loop;
end $$;
```

Usage:

```
create temp table temp_table(id int);

select rec_function(4);

select *
from temp_table;
```

Comment: ugh, the naming got screwed up, my bad. However, given the scope of my natural data, allowing it to go down branches is not going to be feasible. It was taking postgres 15 minutes to gather the data on my data set, growing the object list to about 40 million rows, only to have the DISTINCT bring it back down to about 11.  With proper duplicate detection, this should have taken ~100ms.  My plpgsql solution (which I came up with between posting and adding the bounty) takes 300-500ms for that data set, but, compared to pure sql, longer on a non-pathological test.

Comment: Well, my statements about eliminating duplicates were probably too categorical. 11 unique values out of 40 million is indeed a case in which an early elimination of duplicates may be beneficial. See the updated answer.

Comment: That's what I had before as well (see the very top of the original question) - the problem is that each branch gets its own array, so if we have 123567 and 245, then we see 567 duplicated. In such a small example, DISTINCT is a fine answer, but with pathological cases, which, unfortunately, aren't likely to be entirely rare, not so much.

Comment: Indeed, I must have overlooked the query in the question. I've added a solution based on a recursive function.

Comment: Your plpgsql solution almost matches the plpgsql solution I had come up with except I used an array instead of a temp table (fairly minor unless I have multiple queries hitting this proc at the same time perhaps), which mostly confirms my thinking that, out of the box at least, pure sql isn't going to really suffice.

Answer (score 3):

I know is't a rather old question, but I'm a little amazed that no one suggested removing `all` from the `union` to eliminate the duplicates early. It is a rather simple way to prevent duplicates in the result of a recursive CTE, but it does have its caveats — such a result must include only real fields, i.e. no calculated on the go `depth`, `path` or whatever.

Using the sample data from the question with this query (reformatted a little from the original):

```
with recursive
rdeps as (
  select dep.id, dep.id as dependson
  from objectdependencies as dep
  where dep.dependson = 4 -- starting point
  union
  select self.id, dep.dependson
  from rdeps as self 
  join objectdependencies as dep on dep.dependson = self.id
)
select dependson from rdeps;
```

I get precisely `1`, `2`, and `3`.

Moreover, this solution prevents endless loop in case of a cycle in dependencies. However, it does not detect it, as it doesn't and can't show that there is a cycle, it just prevents an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use from This for find duplicate value

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [FieldName] ORDER BY [FieldName])[Rank],* 
FROM TableName)
SELECT * 
FROM  cte 
WHERE cte.[Rank]>1
```

Comment: Finding the duplicate is almost exactly the opposite of what I would like to have.  I want to stop the branch when a duplicate is found, but continue all other branches to find all nodes involved in a path without wasting time on duplicates.