# how to identify the duplicate rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have one table which 4 columns code1,code2,code3 and code4

so those can contain the data like below (showing 2 records below)

```
code1=xy code2=yz code3='' code4=''
code1=xy code2='' code3=yz code4=''
```

We need to make the 2 record as duplicate as it contains the same data scattered on differnt columns. please help me

Comment: Does the order of the values in the columns matter, i.e is `code1=1, code2=2` equivalent to `code1=2, code2=1` ?

Comment: Please show us more sample data.

Comment: What is your table called?

Comment: code1=1, code2=2 equivalent to code1=2, code2=1  Yes its same.. So the values can scatter across the columns. Please help me

Comment: Is there a primary key column? What's its name?

Comment: main table will have employeeid...which is mapped in the above table  so the above will have employeeid,code1,code2,code2,code4,line1 as the columns

Comment: What results are you looking for?  What does "We need to make the 2 record as duplicate " mean?

Comment: As two records are same so we need to make one record as duplicate. Please help

Comment: Can you Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use from This for find duplicate value

[Detect duplicate items in recursive CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477946/detect-duplicate-items-in-recursive-cte/50539051#50539051)

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [FieldName] ORDER BY [FieldName])[Rank],* 
FROM TableName)
SELECT * 
FROM  cte 
WHERE cte.[Rank]>1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably have here is a many to one relationship that someone has shoehorned into a single table and this will create more problems than it solves.

I'd suggest fixing your schema and then you'll be able to more easily solve this kind of problem.

For example if the columns code1, code2, code3 and code4 are on an employee table like this:

```
employee table
|employeeid |name |code1 |code2 |code3 |code4 |
|1          |bob  |xy    |yz    |      |      |
|2          |sam  |xy    |      |yz    |      |
```

Then you could restructure your data into two tables:

```
employee table
|employeeid |name |
|1          |bob  |
|2          |sam  |

code table
|employeeid |code |
|1          |xy   |
|1          |yz   |
|2          |xy   |
|2          |yz   |
```

This will make it much easier to find people with the same codes (and remove what is probably an arbitrary limit where you have four codes)

Comment: I agree with that.. But its a third party tool.. So i cannot change the DB design and it could be great if you can suggest some solution for the above problem with out any desing changes

Comment: fair enough - it can help if you mention that kind of condition in the question ;)

Comment: Sorry about that.. Please help me

Comment: Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the ordering of the columns, you can get the unique values by doing:

```
select distinct x.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then col end) as col1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then col end) as col2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then col end) as col3,
             max(case when seqnum = 4 then col end) as col4
      from (select col, row_number() over (order by col desc) as seqnum
            from (values (col1), (col2), (col3), (col4)) v(col)
           ) x
     ) x
```

Comment: Seems this is working.. but i need one more column along with col1,col2,col3 and col4 then only it will work for me. Appreciate your help Plz

Comment: Hi Gordon, Seems to be close but not working as expected. please help