# SQL Server - Remove duplicate rows and maintain existing primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with various column which i need to de-dupe, however i need to keep the existing primary key for each row.  Obviously when running SELECT DISTINCT .... without the primary key column (Source_ID) gives me the required outcome when excluding the primary key column.

So how can i get the distinct rows and maintain the existing primary key data.

```
Source table before de-dupe

Source_ID   Title   First_Name  Last_Name   Organisation
1000013     Mr      James       Caine       Company1 
1000014     Ms      Judith      Jason       Company2
1000015     Mr      James       Caine       Company1 


table after de-dupe

Source_ID   Title   First_Name  Last_Name   Organisation
1000013     Mr      James       Caine       Company1 
1000014     Ms      Judith      Jason       Company2
```

Comment: When you say de-dupe, do you mean a `SELECT` statement that only returns the relevant rows, or are you wanting to `DELETE` the repeated data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` like below:

```
SELECT Source_ID, Title, First_Name, Last_Name, Organisation
FROM
    (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by Title, First_Name, Last_Name, Organisation Order by Source_ID) as rn
    FROM YourTable) as tblMain
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Better to put that query into a CTE.  Then, you could also easily do a delete.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want aggregation:

```
select max(source_id) as source_id,
       Title, First_Name, Last_Name, Organisation
from t
group by Title, First_Name, Last_Name, Organisation;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use from This for find duplicate value

```
;WITH cte AS 
(SELECT Source_ID, Title, First_Name, Last_Name, Organisation,
rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by Title, First_Name, Last_Name, Organisation Order by Source_ID 
FROM YourTable)
SELECT * 
FROM WHERE rn > 1
```

[Detect duplicate items in recursive CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477946/detect-duplicate-items-in-recursive-cte/50539051#50539051)